# Android:How to acces excel file which is saved in server

Tags: android

I am trying to access excel sheet which is saved in server but I don't know how ?I know we can access excel file from assets folder but it does not seem right way to do if the excel file is too large..also it is so hard work to do updation..plz help me ..I m stuck

Comment: Just download it from the server and store it on the device ...

Comment: Can you explain more..i didn't get it..

Comment: 1. Let the server serve the document. 2. Download it inside of your android app. 3. Use it in your android app. What have you tried so far? If you don't know how to programm at all you won't find answers here.

Comment: download it inside your app.....??? I want in this way..that i request to ftp server which store my excel file and then it will read the the data from excel file ..i already tried this  example.. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-read-excel-file-from-website.html but it doesnot support higher versions of excel like 2007,2010

Comment: So you're not actually having trouble getting the file but processing it? Please be clear about **what the actual question is**.

Comment: As it is not working for me..so there must be another solution for make this possible... its not about the file...its about how it can be done...!! If u have solution/suggestion then help me

Comment: I can't help for I don't know what the actual isse is. Do you have trouble reading the excel file within your android app? If yes see: https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Thank you...i will come back to u...!!

Comment: @m02ph3u5  can u send me the php file for accesing the excel sheet..!!